# What's the best way to backup/restore the SharePoint Online Terms Store?

Tags: sharepoint-online, term-store

MS lost hundreds of my terms yesterday and has no backup or explanation. I need to find a reliable way of backing up the terms and then restore them so that there are no orphaned documents/list items. Fortunately this happened early and I only have a few thousand orphaned documents.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the Office Dev PnP MMSync tool working from their samples pack (you'll need Visual Studio), you could synchronise down to an on-premises environment (if you have one), then take backups of the term store database on your on-prem environment.

All term GUIDS and labels are synchronised with this tool. It's far from ideal, but the termstore has long been missing a decent "export" facility.

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.MMSSync